# MySQL - how to add "Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)" to a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run a query on my laptop, it takes like a second to execute, but in the production environment, the query lasts 57 seconds (and it crashes the applications - that's written in Ruby On Rails).

I ran this query with **EXPLAIN** and found out that on my laptop is on one table in the query executed

> Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

but this is missing in production (for this table, there's nothing in the **EXTRA** column).

Why is that? How to add **Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)** also to production?

Thank you

**EDIT:** here's the query:

```
SELECT `shippers`.`company_name` 
FROM `shippers` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `shipper_services` 
ON `shipper_services`.`shipper_id` = `shippers`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `services` ON `services`.`id` = `shipper_services`.`service_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `shipper_freight_flow_industries` 
ON `shipper_freight_flow_industries`.`shipper_id` = `shippers`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `freight_flow_industries` 
ON `freight_flow_industries`.`id` = `shipper_freight_flow_industries`.`freight_flow_industry_id` 
WHERE `shippers`.`id` IN (189459, 337334, 149804, 36046, 158403, 165682, 153399, 51471, 211796, 164984, 61118, 56497, 340353, 66525, 225635, 250376, 33237, 69140, 151777, 169530, 245255, 142246, 259597, 57889, 262986, 167803, 33459, 40561, 65878, 44356, 169545, 210358, 25555, 4563, 82538, 157765, 232509, 213248, 37380, 258965, 340616, 340926, 143314, 195553, 60845, 161463, 255789, 38942, 192219, 811, 64672, 13530, 340809, 66030, 157223, 347671, 176886, 157812, 348255, 37357, 337003, 5588, 24257, 164799, 230717, 153801, 171835, 66595, 176780, 250184, 3262, 201519, 223904, 241992, 254167, 242449, 5368, 23903, 52571, 7198, 40135, 340494, 11851, 171285, 26810, 231003, 193961, 341161, 17122, 56660, 348103, 145539, 176912, 19716, 196617, 34803, 75444, 62418, 149606, 158879, 242439, 63291, 80548, 170778, 184871, 254549, 337109, 151159, 255077, 38939, 191926, 337720, 205999, 247471, 258106, 40225, 52599, 141637, 207246, 247541, 258876, 52629, 65936, 164884, 192238, 247588, 13669, 26875, 41763, 52700, 143009, 154515, 174092, 192869, 210753, 248501, 13835, 27222, 43017, 52995, 154640, 165368, 176390, 235034, 248829, 261492, 16610, 29589, 43109, 143661, 195373, 211866, 236874, 33148, 67629, 145474, 166592, 212358, 236937, 263276, 353, 18193, 44479, 68389, 196133, 241530, 251862, 331361, 770, 45861, 68982, 145652, 157945, 177022, 214534, 241659, 253705, 332487, 349455, 20303, 46852, 61001, 147373, 158198, 178036, 200139, 220189, 241765, 253987, 334046, 350465, 21532, 46970, 149478, 170761, 178187, 334167, 350466, 3285, 22934, 48334, 77067, 170770, 184809, 201905, 224892, 254293, 23063, 51366, 203181, 37607, 63370, 80720, 163426, 170798, 203424, 226486, 243809, 244904, 63388, 81420, 163553, 170800, 203819, 228767, 244936, 6057, 24664, 52584, 152229, 164080, 170812, 192096, 229759, 257935, 25300, 52592, 65635, 82575, 152798, 164171, 170817, 192179, 206647, 229772) 
AND ((
          (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.5194174327134307)*COS(-1.664517065837707)*COS(RADIANS(shippers.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(shippers.longitude))+
          COS(0.5194174327134307)*SIN(-1.664517065837707)*COS(RADIANS(shippers.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(shippers.longitude))+
          SIN(0.5194174327134307)*SIN(RADIANS(shippers.latitude))))*3963.1899999999996)
          <= 5.0)) AND (store_location = "0" AND corporate_hq = "0" AND queued_item="0") 
GROUP BY company_name  ORDER BY count_of_facilities DESC)
```

production:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                           | type   | possible_keys     | key       | key_len | ref                                                                   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shippers                        | range  | PRIMARY,idx_store | PRIMARY   | 4       | NULL                                                                  |    245 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipper_services                | ref    | idx_combo         | idx_combo | 5       | db_production.shippers.id                                              |      2 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | services                        | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | db_production.shipper_services.service_id                              |      1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipper_freight_flow_industries | ALL    | NULL              | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                                  | 241609 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | freight_flow_industries         | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | db_production.shipper_freight_flow_industries.freight_flow_industry_id |      1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Indexes:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                           | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| shipper_freight_flow_industries |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      241609 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

localhost:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                           | type   | possible_keys     | key       | key_len | ref                                                                               | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shippers                        | range  | PRIMARY,idx_store | PRIMARY   | 4       | NULL                                                                              |  245 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipper_services                | ref    | idx_combo         | idx_combo | 5       | development.shippers.id                                              |    2 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | services                        | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | development.shipper_services.service_id                              |    1 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipper_freight_flow_industries | ALL    | NULL              | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                                              |   58 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | freight_flow_industries         | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY   | 4       | development.shipper_freight_flow_industries.freight_flow_industry_id |    1 | Using index                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Indexes:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                           | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| shipper_freight_flow_industries |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |          58 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: don't know why this is happening, but maybe you can add index with `shipper_id` in `shipper_freight_flow_industries`

Comment: Pls provide the indexes on shipper_freight_flow_industries table!

Comment: @Shadow added, thanks.

Comment: Also `ANALYZE TABLE` may help

Comment: Yep, try @Fabricator's suggestion and add that index.

Answer (score 14):

This is a bug with Mysql https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69721

You can run the query with

```
set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off'
```

Answer (score 10):

This post really asks 2 questions.

The implicit one is something like "How can I improve performance for this query on my production system?".
As already noticed by @Fabricator, the answer is "Add an index on `shipper_id` to the `shipper_freight_flow_industries` table", which is the recommended way as soon as joins create a huge number of combinations due to the size of the involved tables.

Regarding the explicit one:

> Why is that? How to add **Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)** also to production?

The time difference obviously comes from the size of the `shipper_freight_flow_industries` table: 58 in the laptop DB, 241,609 in the production DB.

And the fact that only the laptop uses a join buffer is likely due to the `join_buffer_size` variable (look at [this MySql page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)): it's probably set to its default value (256K) on both systems.
So it's used on the laptop DB, but on the production system it's too small to allow using it for the number of rows involved.

As stated above, adding an index is the preferred way to improve this query performance, but it might be interesting to try using a very large `join_buffer_size` without an index, and compare the results.
This solution might be a good alternative in some peculiar cases, such as if this index has no other use than for this query and if furthermore it's dwelling other tasks like its table updates.