# MySQL - Slow Query when adding multiple derived tables - Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

For my query, the two derived tables at the bottom are causing a crazy slow up for this query. The query, as is, takes about 45-55 seconds to execute.. NOW, when i remove just one of those derived tables (it does not matter which one) the query goes down to 0.1 - 0.3 seconds. My questions; Is there an issue with having multiple derived tables? Is there a better way to execute this? My indexes all seem to be correct, I will also include the explain from this query.

```
select t.name as team, u.name as "REP NAME", 
  count(distinct activity.id) as "TOTAL VISITS", 
  count(distinct activity.account_id) as "UNIQUE VISITS",
  count(distinct placement.id) as "COMMITMENTS ADDED",

  CASE WHEN 
    count(distinct activity.account_id) = 0 THEN (count(distinct 
    placement.id) / 1) 
    else (cast(count(distinct placement.id) as decimal(10,2)) / 
    cast(count(distinct activity.account_id) as decimal(10,2)))
  end as "UNIQUE VISIT TO COMMITMENT %",

  case when o.mode='basic' then count(distinct placement.id) else 
    count(distinct(case when placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' 
    then placement.id else 0 end)) 
  end as "COMMITMENTS FULFILLED",

  case when o.mode='basic' then 1 else 
    (CASE WHEN 
     count(distinct placement.id) = 0 THEN (count(distinct(case when 
     placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' then placement.id else 0 
    end)) / 1) 
    else (cast(count(distinct(case when 
    placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' then placement.id else 0 
    end)) as decimal(10,2)) / cast(count(distinct placement.id) as 
    decimal(10,2)))
    end) end as "COMMITMENT TO FULFILLMENT %"

from lpmysqldb.users u
left join lpmysqldb.teams t on t.team_id=u.team_id
left join lpmysqldb.organizations o on o.id=t.org_id
left join (select * from lpmysqldb.activity where 
  org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and completed_at>='2018-05-01' and 
  completed_at<='2018-06-01' and tag='visit' and accountname is not 
  null and (status='active' or status='true' or status='1')) as 
  activity on activity.user_id=u.id
left join (select * from lpmysqldb.placements where 
  orgid='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and placementdate>='2018-05-01' and 
  placementdate<='2018-06-01' and (status IN ('1','active','true') or 
  status is null)) as placement on placement.userid=u.id

where u.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
  and (u.status='active' or u.status='true' or u.status='1')
  and istestuser!='1'
group by u.org_id, t.name, u.id, u.name, o.mode
order by count(distinct activity.id) desc
```

[image]

Thank you for assistance!

I have edited below with changing the two bottom joins from joining on subqueries to joining on the table directly. Still yielding the same result.

[image]

Comment: To be able to optimize your query, I would have to understand it. I don't. Or should I say: I can't? I have no idea what your tables look like, why they were designed that way, and what you're trying to accomplish with your query. If you would ask me: My first idea would be: Can I get rid of those two subqueries? There's a change that one of them need to be reevaluated for every row of the main query table.

Comment: The basis of it would be getting a list of users and then looping through and grabbing all of their logged data in two specific table: activities and placements. Then a couple extra columns of a combination of the two. Does that help?

Comment: Can't you remove the subqueries and make them normal joins? I think that is possible.

Comment: I have tried that and same result. I will try again and post below the explain.. Are subqueries generally more performant than derived tables?

Comment: Sorry? No you get derived tables (assembled while the query executes) because you're using subqueries. It is better to use existing tables from the database in joins, because they already exist. The result could be the same, I will admit that, but a join with a database table is almost always better than a join with a subquery (exceptions always exist).

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert on the terminology yet. But yes that was my question. Changing from the join subquery to a "left join lpmysqldb.activity activity on....." yields the same result (timewise). Like I said in the intial, when I remove just one of the last two joins, it will execute in <1 second. It is weird when they are both included, it is that much different.

Comment: I have also updated my initial with the new "explain". Again, thank you for the help.

Comment: Lesson that you should be learning today: writing complex queries isn't cool, doesn't mean anything and they're difficult to debug or optimize. Avoid it. True genius lies in simplicity.

Comment: I think the 'explain' looks better. For one there are less rows, and no derived tables. However, one line is still reporting: "Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)". I found a bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69721 but that doesn't always mean that you have the same problem, but you can try this tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375065/mysql-how-to-add-using-join-buffer-block-nested-loop-to-a-query?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: So how would a query like this be avoided when all that data is needed in the table? Stored Procedures?

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks for the assistance KIKO

Comment: Yes, that is so true. Keeping it simple is the challenge. It starts with the design of your tables: What kind of queries will I run on these tables? What is the best design given these demands?

Comment: I find that splitting a query into multiple simpler queries often helps. You can use intermediate tables to store results in memory. They don't shoot men to the moon with a one-stage rocket. But optimizing is an art form, there are no definitive answers for every situation.

Comment: @nickbrleet - `(u.status='active' or u.status='true' or u.status='1')` is awful for optimization; clean up the data -- pick _one_ way to express the concept.

Comment: @nickbrleet - `completed_at>='2018-05-01' and 
  completed_at<='2018-06-01'` -- That's one month plus one day.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @nickbrleet - `count(distinct ...) as decimal(..,2)` -- Why have decimal places on an integer quantity??

Comment: @RickJames thanks for the feedback but neither of those comments help the initial question. status, data is aggregated and comes in different ways so need checks in for those; date ranges are parameterized, so those are just for test runs so it does not matter; i cast them because it converts 1s and 0s for some reason so its a simple fix. Again, not the issue but thanks anyways

Comment: If you don't need `LEFT`, ditch it.  That _may_ open up new Optimization choices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SLIGHTLY restructured query of your same.  Might be simplified as the last two subqueries are all pre-aggregated for your respective counts and count distincts so you can use those column names directly instead of showing all the count( distinct ) embedded throughout the query.

I also tried to simplify the division by multiplying a given count by 1.00 to force decimal-based precision as result.

```
select 
      t.name as team, 
      u.name as "REP NAME", 
      Activity.DistIdCnt as "TOTAL VISITS", 
      Activity.UniqAccountCnt as "UNIQUE VISITS",
      Placement.DistIdCnt as "COMMITMENTS ADDED",

      Placement.DistIdCnt / 
         CASE WHEN Activity.UniqAccountCnt = 0 
           THEN 1.00 
           ELSE Activity.UniqAccountCnt * 1.00 
           end as "UNIQUE VISIT TO COMMITMENT %",

      case when o.mode = 'basic' 
           then Placement.DistIdCnt
           else Placement.DistFulfillCnt
           end as "COMMITMENTS FULFILLED",

      case when o.mode = 'basic' 
           then 1 
           else ( Placement.DistFulfillCnt /
                     CASE when Placement.DistIdCnt = 0
                          then 1.00
                          ELSE Placement.DistIdCnt * 1.00
                          END TRANSACTION )
           END as "COMMITMENT TO FULFILLMENT %"
   from 
      lpmysqldb.users u
         left join lpmysqldb.teams t 
            on u.team_id = t.team_id
            left join lpmysqldb.organizations o 
               on t.org_id = o.id
        left join
        ( select
                user_id,
                count(*) as AllRecs,
                count( distinct id ) DistIdCnt,
                count( distinct account_id) as UniqAccountCnt
             from
                lpmysqldb.activity
             where 
                    org_id = '555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
                and completed_at>='2018-05-01' 
                and completed_at<='2018-06-01' 
                and tag='visit' 
                and accountname is not null 
                and status IN ( '1', 'active', 'true') 
             group by
                user_id ) activity 
            on u.id = activity.user_id

         left join 
         ( select
                 userid,
                 count(*) AllRecs,
                 count(distinct id) as DistIdCnt,
                 count(distinct( case when commitmentstatus = 'fullfilled' 
                                      then id 
                                      else 0 end )) DistFulfillCnt
              from 
                 lpmysqldb.placements
              where 
                     orgid = '555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852'
                 and placementdate >= '2018-05-01' 
                 and placementdate <= '2018-06-01' 
                 and ( status is null OR status IN ('1','active','true')
              group by
                 userid ) as placement 
            on u.id = placement.userid
   where 
         u.org_id = '555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
     and u.status IN ( 'active', 'true', '1')
     and istestuser != '1'
   group by 
      u.org_id, 
      t.name, 
      u.id, 
      u.name, 
      o.mode
   order by 
      activity.DistIdCnt desc
```

FINALLY, your inner queries are querying for ALL users.  If you have a large count of users that are NOT active, you MIGHT exclude those users from each inner query by adding those join/criteria there too such as...

```
( ...
              from 
                 lpmysqldb.placements 
                    JOIN lpmysqldb.users u2
                       on placements.userid = u2.id
                      and u2.status IN ( 'active', 'true', '1')
                      and u2.istestuser != '1'
              where … ) as placement
```

Comment: If `istestuser` only has values of 0 or 1, then it is better to say `u2.istestuser = 0` and then add `INDEX(istestuser, status, id)`.

Comment: istestuser can be 0 1 or null so easier to check for != 1 but thanks once again

Comment: @nickbrleet - OK, but that makes my suggested `INDEX` useless.